# Atualização Chrome mudou tamanho dos input type text

Tags: google-chrome, input

Após a última atualização do Google Chrome os `input text` que são mostrados dentro de `jquery dialogs` aumentaram de tamanho na exibição. Fiz algumas pesquisas e tentei corrigir usando o código abaixo:

```
input {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Mas não obtive sucesso. Alguém sabe como contornar isso?[image: Antes]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer alterar o tamanho nas duas proporções(altura e largura)? width funciona para largura, e height para altura, você adiciona as propriedades via css pelos parametros **class** ou **id** do elemento.

Comment: Está assim: `<input type="text" name="data_sol_fatura" id="data_sol_fatura" size="12" />` mas após a atualização do navegador esse "12" ficou muito maior na renderização da tela.

Comment: Diminuir o size para valores menores não resolve o problema? :p

Comment: Resolve mas imagina fazer isso para todo o sistema. Tenho inúmeras telas com inúmeros input text. Imagio que deva existir alguma forma de configurar o css para o padrão anterior que o chrome usava.

Comment: Então você quer aplicar a qualquer input que for encontrado na pagina?

Comment: @WagnerSoares, seu sistema já utiliza algum script para retirar o css aplicado pelo browser? Como o normalize.css

Comment: @Vinícius não utilizao o normalize.css vou procurar e testar

Comment: @Vinícius o problema persiste mesmo com o normalize.css.

Comment: Pode descrever na pergunta o estilo do seu input? Existe algum?

Comment: Coloquei um print de uma tela o antes e o depois da atualização do chrome.

Comment: @WagnerSoares Um jeito de saber o que ficou diferente em uma versão e outra é abrir o Developer Tool (F12) e ir na aba Elements  e procurar em Styles o estilo computado para os seus inputs. 
Se não estiver usando estilos próprios, vai ver uns estilos que fazem parte do próprio Google Chrome como `user agent stylesheet` compare em ambas as versões para entender o que mudou e corrija fixando no seu CSS.